# scala-maven-plugin and Scala

Tags: scala, maven, plugins

I have a scala project that depends on 2.11.8. Hence that is the version I am declaring as a dependency in my project. I have configured the maven-scala-plugin as follows.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.11.8</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
                <testSourceDir>src/test/scala</testSourceDir>
                <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                <jvmArgs>
                    <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
                    <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
                </jvmArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

However, when I build my project I receive:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.11:compile (default) on project myproject: wrap: org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
>   [ERROR] [FATAL] Non-parseable POM /Users/myuser/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.8/scala-compiler-2.11.8.pom: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG seen ....uk/main?ParticipantID=nmum6rqpq5q6gkm3933n3nf9s76onu6r&FailedURI=... @1:265)  @ line 1, column 265

Let me know if there is any additional information that would help resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies for scala in .m2 were corrupt - cleaned them out and did a clean install for everything. All fixed!